# Creating Foreign Id issue in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Okay, I think it's must be simple thing to solve, and I am doing the what the docs says. but still having the error message of

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced
> table 'projects' (SQL: alter table `contents` add constraint
> `contents_project_id_foreign` foreign key (`project_id`) references
> `projects` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

And not quite understand why it failed to open referanced table of `projects`

**projects schema**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('pid');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->nullable(true);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and the **contents schema**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('project_id')->constrained("projects")
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->char("opening_times")->nullable(true);
        $table->string("notice")->nullable(true);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

then I run the command `php artisan migrate` I am getting that error message above... what is the thing that I am missing here?

Comment: Is the `projects` table being created before the `contents` table?

Comment: database is empty. I run migrate and I thought Laravel should be decide which one is the first the create, in the end parent/pivot table is project and the contents is the child.   @WillWalsh

Comment: Laravel doesn't 'decide', the order of the filenames in the /database/migrations folder determine the order of the migrations. Ensure that the filename for the `projects` table is listed above the `contents` table in the directory listing.

Comment: oooh, I get it. thank you for pointing that out. Django doesn't need that kind of ordering. so, that make me confused

Comment: No worries. I had the same issue early on using Laravel and it confused me until I figured that out. Good luck on your coding journey! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because migration excecute content first. You can rename the migration name. Migration excecution is ordering by name ascending. You can do renaming like this ex : 2021_03_16_001456_create_projects_table.php
2021_03_16_001457_create_contents_table.php

It should be done I think